# Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::venue does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm creating a multi authentication system, I'm trying to display data contained in a model named 'venue' of a logged in venue, and I cant seem to access it, it keeps throwing the error in title? There isnt much helpful information online about this, and I was wondering if someone could lend a hand?

venue.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.auth')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                        {{ dd(Auth::venue()) }}
                    <div class="card-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

login controller:

```
public function venueLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('venue')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/venue');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
```

Guards:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],




'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
        'customer-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'venue' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'venues',
        ],
        'venue-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'venues',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

I would be so grateful for any help! Really having trouble with laravel :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it that way.

To get the model from the guard you are using, you have to specify on wich guard you want to work and then retrieve data via `user()` method

`Auth::guard('venue')->user()`

You may be disappointed because most of the time, when you want to get the information from the user connected in a system with only one guard, you only use `Auth::user()`.

In fact, this is because the default guard used by Laravel is `web`, which is the one most people use for a simple login system. So you don't need to specify `guard()`, just `user()` hence the error you made in using `venue()` directly thinking that it was a method that was added to the Auth object by changing your configuration. But when you work with specific guards, you are required to specify via the Auth object which guard you want to work on (in this case `venue`) before you can call the `user()` method on it to get the user's information.